# Zooming in using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, error, zoom

I have a problem with a shapefile that until this morning was working perfectly fine.
When I zoom to layer, the shapefile is whole, everything normal. After 1 mouse scroll, the shapefile dissapears, leaving just 1 element visible (as in the printscreens). I have tried redownloading the shp, restarting QGIS, restarting the computer. Nothing worked. 
[image: Zoom to layer]

[image: one zoom unit further]

Comment: I'm not sure that "Yet another bug in QGIS" is a very constructive way to title a question. It is not descriptive (and given that is is free software), not very grateful either.

Comment: do you have the same behavior with any shapefiles ? Did you try a deeper look on geometry with check-validity processing tools http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools.html#check-validity ?

Comment: I had similar problems when I projected shapefile with wrong CRS...

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem. There was apparently a strange .qix file in the shapefile folder which, when deleted, solved my problem.